# Hotkey for scaling in photoshop

Tags: photoshop, hotkeys

Is there a hotkey that "scale to the same scale that I just scaled"?

I was scaling a layer earlier today by a percentage in photoshop. I then dragged in another layer from another document and then accidentally hit a key combination that automatically scaled that layer to the same scale that I had just entered in on the previous layer. I can't figure out what keys I hit to make this happen, but it sure would be nice to know what i did.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly isn't a question for stack overflow...
However, I do believe you hit Ctrl + T (PC) which is transform again. Edit -> Transform -> Transform again. It saves the last transformation - be it a move, scale, rotation (or combination) allowing you repeat the transformation over once more.

Answer (score 1):

The scale hotkey in Photoshop on a mac is **Shift + Option**.  Here is the workflow:

1. Select the layer you wish to scale
2. Command + T (transform)
3. Shift + Option + Click and drag to scale

Comment: What are the scale options for other operating systems?

Comment: Windows: Use the Move Tool (V), drag the square on the sides to resize
; Press Shift + Alt and drag a corner for resizing symmetrically

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **ctrl + T** in windows and **Command + T** in mac